# Why CAPS LOCK in AMS mode in LyX?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, lyx, small-caps, amsart

I am trying to use the AMS article in LyX. I want my output to look like the following (note margins are the same for the entire paragraph and not all letters are capitalized):

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
 \begin{doublespace}

 \section{Introduction. AbCdEfGEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE EE EE EE}\end{doublespace}
```

However, here is what I have:

[image]

and here is the PDF:

[image]

The first 6 letters I typed were AbCdEf, yet they are all capitalized in my document. How can I edit this so that not all letters are capitalized (for each section and subsection)? I also don't want all the letters in the word "Introduction" to be capitalized, but LyX does this once I click "Section."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default for the AMS article document class - sections are set in small caps. These defaults are set in what is called a *layout* (and stored in a `.layout` file). Layouts are available in the in the `Resources/layouts` subfolder of your LyX folder, if you want to take a gander. Specifically, the AMS article layout is available in `amsart.layout`.

If you wish to change parts of a layout, you can do so by means of a *local* layout. Follow Document > Settings... > Local Layout and add the following:

```
Format 49
Style Section
Align        Center
Font
  Series     Medium
  Shape      Default
  Size       Normal
EndFont
TocLevel 1
End

Style Section*
Align        Center
Font
  Series     Medium
  Shape      Default
  Size       Large
EndFont
End
```

The above updates the `Section` and `Section*` styles to use a `Default` shape (formerly `SmallCaps`). Note that this will only change the display within LyX, and not the PDF output generated via pdfLaTeX. For this you also need to change the way the `\section` and `\section*` titles are handled under the AMS class. Therefore, additionally add the following to your Document > Settings... > LaTeX preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}
    {1}
    \z@
    {.7\linespacing \@plus \linespacing}
    {.5\linespacing}
    {\normalfont\centering}% \scshape
  }
\makeatother
```

The above preamble addition will change the font for both `\section` and `\section*` to be void of `\scshape` on the LaTeX side.

LyX input:

[image]

LaTeX output:

[image]

Comment: I edited the preamble. When I enter your code into the local layout, it says "layout is invalid."

Comment: @TheSubstitute: What version of LyX are you using? Perhaps try without the line "Format 49".

Comment: That worked! I am using 2.0. Now let me reread your answer and see what happens. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TheSubstitute: [LyX](http://lyx.org) is currently on version 2.1.4. I'd suggest an upgrade, just because.